# Issues with footline in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,envcountsect]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}


\definecolor{crimsonred}{RGB}{153,0,0} 

\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=white, bg=red!50!black}


\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\tiny}


\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{2em}}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

[image]

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,comment}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that demonstrates the issue. If I use just the code you posted, and create a sample frame, the issue does not arise, but also, the output looks nothing like your screenshot. So you're obviously using additional settings or commands not included above.

Comment: I seem to have resolved the issue.
In the line

\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}

since "footline=authortitle", the footer included author name and the title.
When I changed to footline=authorinstitute", the footer included author name and the institute name. 
This left the footer with just author name, institute name and the slide number.
(Previously ,I was trying to fit in my long title into the footer.).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.